# Delphi XE5 - Debug mode for Android

Tags: android, delphi, debugging, delphi-xe5

I don't know how to run my Android applications (built with Delphi XE5) in a step-by-step debug mode.
How to do this?

Following information may be helpfull:

- *Build configuration* is *Debug*;
- Apps are executed on a real device;
- I've tried to place breakpoints, and *Run*, and *Step Over*, and *Run to cursor* - it seems nothing works!

**UPD:**

- System is MIUI, device is from Lenovo (with NEON support);
- Delphi XE5 upd2 (Trial);
- *USB debugging* (now) is turned on;
- Apps built with Android Studio are debugged fine.

**UPD 2:**

- <strike>I use *ADB Over WiFi* to connect to device;</strike> (irrelevant)
- I've tried to explicitly specify the app for debugging and turn on *Wait for debugger* in the settings - app freezes at the start with a message *"Waiting for Debugger"*;
- Device is visible in `adb devices`, in Android *Target* list in the *Project Manager*, and sample apps run fine; just without debugging!

**UPD 3:**

It is Delphi XE5 issue. After upgrade to XE6 I was able to debug apps in a step-by-step mode.

Comment: It works fine for me, although the debugger sometimes causes an exception. I never use the emulator for development. Have you turned on the debugging options on your device? (Settings->Developer Options->Debugging, check USB Debugging in Jelly Bean and KitKat).

Comment: @KenWhite, I've turned on the debugging options, but still it doesn't work. IDE layout changes to Debug for a moment and then backs to Default. Now I guess that device/OS is buggy.

Comment: Can you actually run a blank application on your device? Can you see it in the Project Manager Targets under Android? Have you made that the target? I'd start with [this wiki page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Enabling_USB_Debugging_on_an_Android_Device), and make sure you've followed all the steps up to (and including) running your app on the device, and then running one of the sample apps in the Samples\MobileCodeSnippets (available from the XE5 folder in your start menu) to see if it can be debugged. I have a Galaxy S3 and a Nexus 7 tablet, and both work fine.

Comment: @KenWhite, thank you for sharing your experience! I know now that not everyone has problems with debug:)
Updated question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any experience with ADB/WiFi debugging. (I don't really have a need to do so, because USB is so simple to use; it's not an issue for me to be tethered with a cable during development.)

Comment: @KenWhite, it's another my problem: I can't connect ADB over USB :(

Comment: That's strange, if it shows up in the Targets correctly. ??

Comment: Have you tried starting adb manually yourself, and specifying a target device (adb -s), as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)?

Comment: Thank you. Your advice about [ADB driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) was helpull. Now I can see my device when it's connected over USB. (I'm almost sure I have installed USB driver previously; the key step was to select driver from a list manually.) But the main issue remains open.

Comment: In the end, it seems to be an issue with this specific device and Delphi XE. On another device (Xiaomi Red Rice) debugging works fine.

Comment: simular issue with Delphi XE8 and Android devices: Lenovo A5500 and Huawei P7. FMS application. In the same application debugging works for iOS (inside VMWare) and of course for Windows :)

Debugging more on Anrdoid devices enabled. All simptoms -- the same as described for XE5.

Host OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64. Running with Admin rights. UAC enabled.

Following documentation from http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Debugging_Multi-Device_Applications